# Getting 403 error after deployed Laravel app

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment

I deployed a simple laravel aplication on heroku but I'm getting a lot of 403 erros on my css and js files as you can see in the image. How can I solve this? I tried a lot of stuffs like changing the way to call the files {{asset('css/app.css') }} or that way /css/app.css none of these solved the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo9dd.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files are accessible if you appended `public/`

http://saldoprojeto.herokuapp.com/vendor/adminlte/vendor/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css

> Doesn't work

http://saldoprojeto.herokuapp.com/public/vendor/adminlte/vendor/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css

> Works fine

so you need to tell Heroku to use the public directory as the root directory

`Procfile`

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

PS: the 403 forbidden status is for trying to access a file in the composer vendor directory which is not and shouldn't be publicly accessible

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked like magic wow thanks. My Procfile was written as  " web:vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ " I just wrote like " web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ " putting a 'space' between web: string and worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem